# Laravel + query from DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Good day! :)

The problem is that I can't (don't understand, and don't know) how to specify a comparison of two tables in one query.

We have 2 tables:

1. cars
2. items

cars structure:

- id
- car_id
- price

inventory structure:

- id
- user_id
- car_id

```php
$cars = \DB::table('cars')
        ->select('cars.id', 'cars.car_id','cars.name', 'cars.price')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();
```

In views/pages/index.blade.php

```
@foreach($cars as $cars)
{{$cars->name}}<br>
Price: {{$cars->price}}<br>
You have: **?????**
@endforeach
```

An example for that should be:

```
CarName
Price: 1600
You have: 2

CarNameTwo
Price: 1400
You have: 0

CarNameMore
Price: 100
You have: 1
```

But, how can I include the "you have"?
I can only get a list of an array of data, like:

```
[
  {
    "car_id":1,
    "car_id":4
  }
]
```

But it won't work in `foreach`.

Comment: Hi there, do you know what version of Laravel you are using? I'm not sure for your case, but I wonder if this might be an opportunity to use something like a ["many to many" relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) or something similar? Otherwise, you might be able to get the results you need via two queries instead of one (e.g., one query for cars and another query for inventory), but that might not be as elegant.

Comment: You can use php function `count()`

Comment: How is user_id related? Are you trying to get a list of cars for a particular user? or a list of users with their inventory?

Answer (score 0):

@h3x3x you don't have `cars.name` in your description of your `cars` table, but you do have that listed in your desired result set. If you did have a column named `name` in your `cars` table, you could get the result set you are looking for by using a `leftJoin`, a `DB::raw()` and a `groupBy` statement in your query, like this:

```
$cars = \DB::table('cars')
    ->leftJoin('inventory', 'cars.car_id', '=', 'inventory.car_id')
    ->select('cars.id', 'cars.name', 'cars.price', \DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT inventory.id)'))
    ->groupBy('cars.car_id')
    ->orderBy('cars.car_id`)
    ->get()
```

This would then return the name of the car as listed in `cars.name`, the price of the car as listed in `cars.price` and the count of the cars (or lack thereof) from the `inventory` table all ordered by `cars.car_id`.

If this isn't what you need please let me know and I'll try to assist further.

Comment: So nice :) it`s work! thank you! but ->where('inventory.user_id', $this->user->id), query limits output, shows olny this users, not all "cars"

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
Laravel v. 6.20.14

This is "very light" example from my big problem :)

[image]

Ok, I'll show you in the picture
*"how it should be"*

We need to get everything out of `cars` table, but count only those that we have
in addition to this count, there are also other lines that need to be displayed, but now not about them

I also manage to conclude ONLY the presence of those machines that are, but not all :(

It is not so important what we have in the table `inventory`
If we try to conclude only by car_id?

Answer (score 0):

So, trial and error systems showed that if we take into account the sample by select, set limited of array in output :((

I absolutely dont have idea how to implement this so that there is a complete list from the cars table

```
$cars = Cars::
leftjoin('inventory', 'cars.car_id', '=', 'inventory.carid')
->where('inventory.user_id', $this->user->id)
->where('inventory.status', 1)
->select('cars.*', DB::raw("inventory.type as type2"), DB::raw('count(inventory.id) as count'), DB::raw("inventory.created_at as time"))
->groupBy('inventory.carid','cars.car_id')
->orderBy('car_id')
->get();
```